# How to debug a workflow assemble that is called by an action in dynamics 365

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I have a HTML web resource(a button) on a form in Dynamics 365 Model driven app. The button uses JavaScript to call an action which further calls the workflow activity. I am unable to figure out how to debug it.

Action:
[action that calls the workflow activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWfiM.png)

Answer (score 0):

On the left panel the second row should show you all the logs of the action. So if it fails for some reason, you can see where and why it fails